# How to change column location on .NET chart

Tags: .net, charts, format

I want to change the alignment of the columns in a .NET Chart (System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart) so that the column starts at the left side of the plot area, not centered on the plot point. I've tried everything. It may seem like a small detail, but this chart will be used dynamically as a control panel for data simulations and I need things to look correct. [image: example]

I've tried 
Thanks for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there isn't a standard solution for this, so I created a workaround.
You need to add two series to your chart, one of the series appears left side of the gridline and the other one appears on the right side. The trick is to make the one on the left side 'transparent'.

```
    ' Creating the two series '
    Dim series1 As New Series("series1")
    Dim series2 As New Series("series2")

    ' Setting the Chart Types '
    series1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column
    series2.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column

    ' Adding some points '
    series1.Points.AddXY(1, 1)
    series1.Points.AddXY(2, 1)
    series1.Points.AddXY(3, 1)

    series2.Points.AddXY(1, 1)
    series2.Points.AddXY(2, 1)
    series2.Points.AddXY(3, 1)

    Chart1.Series.Add(series1)
    Chart1.Series.Add(series2)

    ' The series on the left side of the grid line -> Color : Transparent '
    series1.BorderWidth = 0
    series1.ShadowOffset = 0
    series1.Color = Drawing.Color.Transparent

    ' The series on the right side of the grid line -> Color : Blue '
    series2.BorderWidth = 3
    series2.ShadowOffset = 2
    series2.Color = Drawing.Color.CornflowerBlue

    ' Setting the X Axis '
    Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.IsMarginVisible = False
    Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.Interval = 1
    Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.Maximum = 4
```

Also notice the adjustments for the X Axis. The `IsMarginVisible = False` removes the margin on the X Axis, so there isn't any room between the Y Axis and the first column.